# Could reincarnation be intergalactic?

Tags: rebirth, cosmology, samsara

According to any scripture, is the process of reincarnation within Samsara always intra-galactic (the self stays on Earth and reincarnates as people or animals), or are there any texts which could be interpreted that the self, possibly, reincarnates upon other worlds? And, are there any verses which may support the idea that there are "higher" and "lower" worlds, other than Earth, which reflect the sum of the dharma of its inhabitants?

Comment: It is possible. For e.g., kAkabhUsunDa states that some of his reincarnations are as a god.